# SQL group where clause by employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query that return employees:

```
Name     Form
Bob       abc
Bob       gfd
Bob       fgf
John      abc
Gavin     abc
Jessie    ala
Jessie    asf
```

How would I say if abc exists for the employee then result = yes and if abc doesnt exist then no?
What I would want to see is this:

```
Name   Result
Bob    Yes
John   Yes
Gavin  Yes
Jessie  No
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2000+, use:

```
  SELECT e.name,
         COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN e.form = 'abc' THEN 'Yes' END), 'No') AS result
    FROM EMPLOYEES e
GROUP BY e.name
```

The MAX portion will return NULL if none of the form values match "abc", which the COALESCE catches to return "No".

Comment: +1 Alternatively, remove the coalesce and change the case to `MAX(CASE WHEN e.form = 'abc' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)` .